# Invoke Child Workflow Activity Asynchronously

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, workflowservice

Team:

I need to invoke a WF activity (XAML) from a WF service (XAMLX) asynchronously.  I am already referencing the Microsoft.Activities.Extensions framework and I'm running on the Platform Update 1 for the state machine -- so if the solution is already in one of those libraries I'm ready!

Now, I need to invoke that activity (XAML) asynchronously -- but it has an output parameter that needs to set a variable in the service (XAMLX).  Can somebody please provide me a solution to this?

Thanks!

---

*** UPDATE ***

Now I can post pictures, *** I think ***, because I have enough reputation!  Let me put a couple out here and try to better explain my problem.  The first picture is the WF Service that has the two entry points for the workflow -- the second is the workflow itself.

This workflow is an orchestration mechanism that constantly restarts itself, and has some failover mechanisms (e.g. exit on error threshold and soft exit) so that we can manage our queue of durable transactions using WF!

Now, we had this workflow working great when it was all one WF Service because we could call the service, get a response back and send the value of that response back into another entry point in a trigger to issue a soft exit.  However, a new requirement has arrisen asking us to make the workflow itself a WF activity in another project and have the Receive/Send-Reply sequences in the WF Service Application project.

However, we need to be able to startup this workflow and forget about it -- then let it know somehow that a soft exit is necessary later on down the road -- but since WF executes on a single thread this has become a bit challenging at best.

[image: WF Service Sequence]

[image: WF Activity Sequence]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking in XAML activities Parallel and ParallelForEach are how you perform asynchrony.

The workflow scheduler only uses a single thread (much like UI) so any activity that is running will typically be running on the same thread, unless it implements AsyncCodeActivity, in which case you are simply handing back the scheduler thread to the runtime while waiting for a callback from whichever async code your AsyncCodeActivity implementation is calling.

Therefore are you sure this is what you want to achieve? Do you mean you want to run it after you have sent your initial response? In this case place your activity after the Send Reply.

Please provide more info if these suggestions don't answer your question./

**Update:**
The original requirement posed (separating implementation from the service Receive/Send activities) may actually be solved by hosting the target activity as a service. See the following link
http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2011/09/02/building-an-enterprise-workflow-system-with-wf4/

Comment: We have a requirement that is forcing us to place all of our messaging (Receive/Send-Reply) in one project and then the actual flow for those messages in XAML activities in another project.  So, what I need to do is spawn that XAML activity between the Receive/Send-Reply activities, allow it to set its one output parameter which is a state object (allows me to communicate with it later) and then return to the sender.

Comment: Don't think this will be possible. If you use a parallel, your xaml activity could use an InOut argument and setting it will affect the bound variable in the parent workflow but you have no way of yielding control back to the workflow. Even if you other parallel branach was in a loop you would be unnecessarily spinning waiting for the variable to be set. Can you seed the state / correlation object from the workflow?

Comment: OK -- so let me ask this question.  Would it be possible to expose a web service to launch the other workflow, but place that instance on the same host as the WF Service that started the process?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "host". The WorkflowServiceHost only takes a single wf service/activity definition. 

Another approach would be to make your target activity a kind of "scope" activity like TryCatch, ForEach etc where the Receive is actually passed to the target activity as an ActivityDelegate and the target activity calls Receive with the relevant arguments

Comment: Yes -- let me clarify myself.  My primary concern with calling a another web service to startup the other workflow is surrounding persistence and monitoring.  These services will be stood up on an IIS Server with AppFabric installed -- and I want to make sure that I'm not starting up hosts all over the place and endangering performance, persistence and monitoring.  The WF Service that is called originally encapsulates all of that.

Comment: I've updated the question but it appears I still can't upload pictures.  I have to admit -- I love this forum but that's a dumb restriction IMHO.

Comment: Why the requirement to have the separate XAML activity? If it is to change the authoring experience then read [my blog post on the subject](http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2011/09/02/building-an-enterprise-workflow-system-with-wf4/). 

If you can break the requirement to return something from the activity in the receive then things should get easier. See my earlier comment about seeding correlation info etc. For the soft-exit you could consider using a CancellationScope with a Pick, where the other branch of the pick is the receive for the incoming message, and/or the error threshold etc.

Comment: This is an awesome post!  I believe this may be exactly what we're looking for -- but I want to clarify something first.  If I'm understanding this post correctly we can publish an endpoint for a XAML workflow by implementing the necessary pieces of the built in WorkflowServiceHost right?      Is it possible that it would also be safe to build XAMLX files that then use the InvokeAsync of the WorkflowInvoker?  My primary concern with that is that it builds a new WorkflowApplication -- I just don't fully understand the ramifications of communicating with it and performance.

Comment: In actual fact it uses the WorkflowServiceHost as is, out of the box, to host the XAML activity as a service. The custom WorkflowServiceHostFactory allows you to configure it which ever way you want. The WSH already supports a standard XAML activity (or anything that derives from Activity), the capability is just never documented well. The creationEndpoint removes the need for a Receive activity to create an instance. You can think of it as hosting an activity as a service without the XAMLX stuff. You could still run the activity using WorkflowInvoker as long as it does not use any Receives.

Comment: Just as a follow up for you. I have forwarded your blog on to our design team and they will be evaluating it and for the time being I was able to break the requirement by working with our architect. You did an amazing job with that article -- and I would love to implement it because I'm pretty sure I've got a grasp on how it works -- but I'll have to hold off for now. Thanks again!